# Rails loop and delete an object as an admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following loop shows each comment associated to the specific item and lets the comment owner(user) to edit or delete a comment. This works just fine.

Now I would the admin to be able to delete a comment. The only problem is that when I click on the delete... all of the comments associated to the specific item get deleted and not just that one.

Any idea how to fix this?

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <% if current_user == comment.user %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", destroy_item_comment_path(comment.item_id, comment.id),
                method: :delete, data: { confirm: I18n.t("comment_delete_alert")}, :class=>"glyphicon glyphicon-trash" %>     
  <% elsif current_admin %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", admin_destroy_item_comment_path(comment.item_id, comment.id),
                method: :delete, data: { confirm: I18n.t("comment_delete_alert")}, :class=>"glyphicon glyphicon-trash" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

controller method:

```
before_action :find_comment, only: [:destroy]

def destroy
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
  flash[:notice] = "Comment has been deleted"
end

def find_comment
  @comment = @item.comments.find(params[:id])
end
```

**Update 1**

server logs when deleting a comment as an admin

```
 Comment Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 213]]
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = $1  [["id", 14]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = $1  [["id", 15]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = $1  [["id", 16]]
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
 Completed 302 Found in 14123ms (ActiveRecord: 36.3ms)
```

Comment: the code is erroneous. what is `@comment` in `destroy`? It's not initialised anywhere.

Comment: You're right @ kiddorails... I just added more information to my question.

Comment: Is this `destroy` action (shown in question) for admin or for normal users?

Comment: @Jagdeep Singh it's located in the admin controller.

Comment: Also, why do you need separate end points for deleting the same comment?

Comment: @Jagdeep Singh i just added the server logs.

Comment: Looking at the logs, i feel you are deleting all the comments of a user in your action AND you have posted the wrong action definition in the question. Please double check.

Comment: @Jagdeep Singh 3 it's really weird because i double checked everything... this the route to the destroy method  `match 'admin/:item_id/comments/:id'=> 'admin_comments#destroy', :via => :delete, :as => :admin_destroy_item_comment` I'm not sure what may be causing this.

Comment: Post your comment model.

Comment: @Dev I feel like something is going wrong with your routes. Why do you need the item id for destroying a comment? You're already providing the comment id, that should be enough. Furthermore, keep in mind that hiding or disabling a link doesn't stop users from executing the action. Authorization should also be checked in the destroy action itself (or in a *before_action* callback). Have a look at shallow routes in the Rails routing guide. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: Also, can you post the full server log of the delete request? It should say what URL was requested, what the params are and what controller/action handled the request. It should also display executed SQL statements, but I see you already posted that part of the request.

Comment: Shouldn't the route to hit be item_comment_path(item, comment), method: :delete ?

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that your routes are not configured properly. You can hit

```
rails routes
```

to check admin_delete_comment_path configuration.

Try changing

```
admin_destroy_item_comment_path(comment.item_id,comment.id)
```

to:

```
destroy_item_comment_path(commend.item_id, comment.id)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't explain OP's statement: _"all of the comments associated to the specific item get deleted and not just that one."_

Comment: Also, if there was no route defined, it would not have the logs as shown in question.